# Space Button in Keyboard Replace Character In UITextview - iOS (Obj-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextview

how to replace character in UITextview to unicode character when i click space button on keyboard?

for example : 
i type ":(" and then i pressing space button the character replacing to be "\ue403".

i want to create emoticon chat in my apps.

Thanks for attention.

Comment: I think the best way is trace the text that inserted in `UITextView` and replace it with the new things. did you try that?

Comment: why not use the emoticons keyboard?

Comment: i did try, but no effect

Comment: agree with @nfarshchi: after composing the message and tapping "send", you parse the message body, detect emoticons text and replace it with your emoticons

Comment: @user1527915 : what you mean by "no effect"?

Comment: did i mean, every i click button space after type ":(", immediately change to "\ue403". Before tapping send button

Comment: keyboard can set to emoticon keyboard??how??

Comment: @user1527915: for converting to emotion suddenly by every space you should trace your text when ever a character added. if it was " " then you should search for suitable emotion for that and replace it sudden. but i think it is not good solution . a lot of processes at same time.

Comment: emotion keyboard as a type of default `I-OS` keyboards that users can select them or not. it not a part of programming

Answer (score 1):

Use the UITextField delegate message:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

What happens in this case is the space will come in as the final string, and the range will have a length of 0. You can query the textfield to get the current string. So you change the "string" to be the char you want, programmatically append it to the textField text, and return NO.